# Intel NUC unattended-upgrades battery power error

Tags: power-management, battery, 21.10, unattended-upgrades, intel-nuc

I have an Intel NUC running Ubuntu 21.10 server. When testing my unattended-upgrades setup (via `sudo unattended-upgrades --dry-run --debug`) I am receiving the following error:

`System is on battery power, stopping`

The NUC doesn't have a battery so there appears to be a system configuration error. After repeated searches I haven't found any reports of similar problems. Does anyone have an idea of what the issue is and how to fix it?

EDIT: Here is the output of the `on_ac_power` script referenced below. I was unable to determine what is causing it to return false when the NUC is certainly on AC power:

```
deploy@deploy-nuc:~▶ ./on_ac_power.sh
+ OFF_LINE_P=no
+ [ -d /sys/class/power_supply/ ]
+ test -d /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001
+ test -r /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001/type
+ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001/type
+ type=USB
+ [ -r /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001/online ]
+ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001/online
+ online=0
+ [ 0 = 1 ]
+ [ 0 = 0 ]
+ OFF_LINE_P=yes
+ test -d /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:002
+ test -r /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:002/type
+ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:002/type
+ type=USB
+ [ -r /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:002/online ]
+ cat /sys/class/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:002/online
+ online=0
+ [ 0 = 1 ]
+ [ 0 = 0 ]
+ OFF_LINE_P=yes
+ [ yes = yes ]
+ exit 1
```

Comment: I posted the output of the `on_ac_power` script above in case anyone can help determine why it is returning `1` for false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why your system believes it is on battery, but it looks like `unattended-upgrades` [calls the external command](https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/blob/5d05cd182325bad80558df53968a06c119f60746/unattended-upgrade#L676) `on_ac_power` to determine if on battery.

The command `on_ac_power` is just [a fairly basic shell script](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/powermgmt-base/-/blob/be7c677978058b86fefdb5988c3633eb46dc576d/on_ac_power), so you might be able to walk through it and figure out why it is returning the wrong value.

As a workaround, you can add to your apt configuration this setting that will tell `unattended-upgrades` to continue when on battery.

```
Unattended-Upgrade::OnlyOnACPower "false";
```

Comment: The apt configuration successfully enabled `unattended-upgrades` to work. The script is outputting false for some reason although I wasn't able to understand why.